# MYSQL - Selecting data from second row in a large table

Tags: mysql, optimization, select, row

I have an external 3rd party program export the database to mysql in real time, and I want to show data for reporting. So, I can't change the structure, because it's being sync in real time.

The table structure is something like this

```
ID | Date       | Transaction
-----------------------------
12 | 2012-11-01 | 200
12 | 2012-11-02 | 250
12 | 2012-11-03 | 150
12 | 2012-11-04 | 1000
12 | 2012-11-05 | 225
....
13 | 2012-11-01 | 175
13 | 2012-11-02 | 20
13 | 2012-11-03 | 50
13 | 2012-11-04 | 100
13 | 2012-11-05 | 180
13 | 2012-11-06 | 195
```

The data are very large and keep getting bigger each day.

What I want to do is to build a report (view table) based on something like this:

```
ID | Date       | Transaction | Prev Day Transaction
----------------------------------------------------
12 | 2012-11-01 | 200         | 0
12 | 2012-11-02 | 250         | 200
12 | 2012-11-03 | 150         | 250
12 | 2012-11-04 | 1000        | 150
12 | 2012-11-05 | 225         | 1000
....
13 | 2012-11-01 | 175         | 0
13 | 2012-11-02 | 20          | 175
13 | 2012-11-03 | 50          | 20
13 | 2012-11-04 | 100         | 50
13 | 2012-11-05 | 180         | 100
13 | 2012-11-06 | 195         | 180
```

I just can't get the fast select statement. Currently the original data is already 283,120 rows. And it will grow like 500 rows daily.

I've tried something like:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT transaction FROM table as t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id 
AND t1.date>t2.date ORDER BY t2.date DESC LIMIT 0,1)
FROM table AS t1
```

It's working, but the select statement is very slow. Most of the time, it's getting cut of in the middle of the operation.

What I need help is a very fast sql statement, which later on I could use to build the view table.

Comment: `What speed you are getting for Select * from trans where id='12'`

Comment: Hi Sami, I'm just testing with random user. From PHPMyadmin, It took 274 data in 0.0008 seconds (showing 0 - 29 data). *edit* as you can see calling the table directly is very fast and has no problem. Problem comes only on trying to get the Previous Data. I just can't seem to get the the correct select statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54a5e/12

```
select t.id,t.cDate,t.cTrans
  ,(case when @pID=t.id then @pTran else 0 end) as preT 
  ,(@pID :=t.id) as `tID`,(@pTran := t.cTrans) as `tTrans` 
from tb_test_1 as t,(select @pID = 0, @pTran = 0) as t2
order by id,cDate;
```

`tID` and `tTrans` column must be retained, and cannot display on page.

Please forgive me as I only know a little english!

Comment: This is almost perfect. In the sqlfiddle, it's ok. But when I'm testing on my real database, the 'preT' filled with [BLOB - 1B], not my numbers (double type cast) . Could you or anybody else help with this?

Comment: Yeehaa. I've fiddle with it and found the correction. Put a ':=' instead of '=' to fix the formula, and use '0.0' instead of '0' to type cast it into decimal. The perfect line should be....... (select `@pID` := 0.0, `@pTran` := 0.0) as t2

Comment: **Oops. Forget to say thank you to everyone who's tried to help and answer. I really appreciate your time and effort. I got many new knowledge just by asking. :D Of course special thank you for Babaoqi for the correct answer. TQ again guys (and gals if any)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this query -

```
SELECT t1.*, COALESCE(t2.transaction, 0) Prev_Day_Transaction FROM trans t1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM trans ORDER BY id, date DESC) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date > t2.date
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.date;

+------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
| id   | date       | transaction | Prev_Day_Transaction |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
|   12 | 2012-11-01 |         200 |                    0 |
|   12 | 2012-11-02 |         250 |                  200 |
|   12 | 2012-11-03 |         150 |                  250 |
|   12 | 2012-11-04 |        1000 |                  150 |
|   12 | 2012-11-05 |         225 |                 1000 |
|   13 | 2012-11-01 |         175 |                    0 |
|   13 | 2012-11-02 |          20 |                  175 |
|   13 | 2012-11-03 |          50 |                   20 |
|   13 | 2012-11-04 |         100 |                   50 |
|   13 | 2012-11-05 |         180 |                  100 |
|   13 | 2012-11-06 |         195 |                  180 |
+------+------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Add composite index (id, date) to the table.

===========================

```
ALTER TABLE mt4_daily
  ADD INDEX IX_mt4_daily_DATE (DATE);

ALTER TABLE mt4_daily
  ADD INDEX IX_mt4_daily (ID, DATE);
```

Comment: Thanks Devart for trying, but the code is still slow (or even not running, waited 30 seconds and I quit the script). I change the table name and the column name I also added the WHERE id='112' GROUP BY... LIMIT 0,50 to make it smaller. I expect it to run in less than a second with only 50 rows, but it's taking so long. Could you help again. tq.

Comment: Have you added suggested index - (id, date)? I think you also need to add index(date).

Comment: Hi Devart, from the phpmyadmin, it seems the index is already there. keyname Primary, BTREE, Unique, No Packed, Field=ID & Date, Cardinality= 0 & 283120, COLLATION A........ Keyname INDEX_ID, BTREE, No Unique, No Packed, Field=ID, cardinality=0, Collation=A ..... keyname INDEX_DATE, BTREE, No unique, No Packed, Field=time, cardinality=0, Collation=A.... And I'm afraid that changing the structure will disturb the real time sync. But if you insist on any changes, I'll try to replicate it into new testing PC. Tq.

Comment: Can you show table structure - CREATE TABLE? Run SHOW CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Hi Devart, I export from the phpmyadmin and erase redundant number fields (all double type cast). CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mt4_daily` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `BALANCE` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LOGIN`,`TIME`),
  KEY `INDEX_LOGIN` (`LOGIN`),
  KEY `INDEX_TIME` (`TIME`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: So, there are no indexes the query requires. I have added two of them, try the first one, analyze the query, run EXPLAIN SELECT, then add second if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the table into few pars through select statements and join them using UNION Set operator. As all set operators are parallel operation you will get the data very quickly. You can divide the data by using the Unique numeric column in your table. e.g.

```
select * from tbl_x where col1%3=0 union
select * from tbl_x where col1%3=1 union
select * from tbl_x where col1%3=2 ...
```

The above sql query divides the data and fetches in parallel way

Comment: Thanks for the parallel processing information. I will remember that. But, my table is basically has a "id" (as in userid) and "date", kindda like a pairing primary key(s). How do you suggest I divide the tables? I basically want the previous day data, and this table divide is new to me. Tq.

Comment: does not matter I think, you have that id column as numeric value right??.. just go with that user_id column alone.

Comment: ok. I'm very newbie here. forgive me for asking something that you might find very obvious. I tried the {SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=112 AND id%2 ORDER BY date LIMIT 0,30} and it's not running.

Comment: Just check ..http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb64be/8
I divided it into 2 parts if you want to make it more..use 3 and union it three times and so on..

Comment: Tq Chella. I see, i get the concept now. I'll try it, although still confuse how to separate the composite index.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to write the query like this:

```
SELECT
  tbl.ID,
  tbl.Date,
  tbl.Transaction,
  COALESCE(tbl1.Transaction,0) as PrevDay
FROM
  tbl left join tbl tbl1
  on tbl.ID = tbl1.ID
     and tbl.Date = tbl1.Date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

(this will work only if you make sure that the table contains all days, if you miss one day, the next day will always show PrevDay as 0, i am not sure if this is what you need).

**EDIT:** i would try this solution that works even if some days are missing:

```
SELECT
  tbl.id,
  tbl.date,
  tbl.Transaction,
  COALESCE(tbl1.Transaction,0) as PrevDay
FROM
  (SELECT tbl.id, tbl.date as d1, max(tbl1.ddate) as d2
   FROM tbl LEFT JOIN tbl tbl1
        ON tbl.id = tbl1.id and tbl.date>tbl1.date
   GROUP BY tbl.id, tbl.date) t
  LEFT JOIN tbl on tbl.id = t.id and DATE(tbl.ddate) = DATE(t.d1)
  LEFT JOIN tbl tbl1 ON tbl1.id = t.id and DATE(tbl1.date) = DATE(t.d2)
```

Comment: Thank you fthiella. Your code almost works. The problem is, my table has a DATETIME, so the {+INTERVAL 1 DAY} not always work. Do you have any suggestion? Also, I would have a Last Day if possible, because sometimes there are holiday, e.g. Friday to Monday. I would like the Monday have the Prev Friday data, if that is not too much to ask. Tq.

Comment: @MartinIvanovich to make it work with datetime you could use this: `and DATE(tbl.Date)=DATE(tbl1.Date + INTERVAL 1 DAY)` but to support previous days instead of day-1 ... you could use a subquery, that works but that also means that it will be much slower.. i'm still thinking if there's a faster solution...

Comment: @MartinIvanovich see my updated answer, the new query is certanly slower than my first one, but i belive it should work....